# Fill object properties with items from a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, listboxitem

I am trying to populate some `DateTime` properties of an object with `DateTime` values from a `listbox`.
My class contains some `DateTime` properties date1,date2,date3.....date30.
My `listbox` items are 01.02.2021,02.02.2021
How to pass the first item of the listbox(01.02.2021) to the date1 property, the second item(02.02.2021) to the date2 property and so on ...

Any recommendations?
My class:

```
public class Ferien
{
public int Id{get; set;}
public DateTime date1 {get; set; }
public DateTime date2 {get; set; }
public DateTime date3 {get; set; }
.
.

}
```

In code behind from wpf window i declare a List and set it as ItemSource of the listbox

```
public List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
DXGDatum.ItemsSource = dates;//my listbox ItemSource
```

then i populate List dates as follows:

```
        var datestart = Convert.ToDateTime(dpstart.Text);//datepicker1
        var dateend = Convert.ToDateTime(dpende.Text);//datepicker2 
        for (var dt = datestart; dt <= dateend; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
         {
            dates.Add(dt);
         }
```

Now i need to iterate over "dates" and set the values as property value

```
Ferien ferien = new(Ferien){date1=dates[0], date2=dates[1]}
```

this works fine but i need to count the items in dates so lets say i have 15 items in List dates i need to populate date1-date15 and not date16-date30. I dont know how to do this in the object initalizer.
Is this possible or do i have to call

```
if(dates[0] !=null
{date1=dates[0]}
```

for every property from date1 to date30?
thx

Comment: It will be more easy for everyone if you hare the code instead of describing it.

Comment: edited my question, thx

Comment: Why would you not have a collection of DateTimes as a single property in your Ferien class? You could directly bind the ItemsSource to that property.

Comment: Hmm, your right i will give it a try. Can u give me some advice how you would do it ?